# How to display tip values of each plot in a stacked bar that created by Core-plot?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

I need help with this, please help me. Here is my situation:

[image: This is what I have now]

This is what I have now. The red plot has value 190. And the yellow plot has 63.3 value. I want to plot the red one above the yellow one. It means the yellow plot has baseValue= 0 and the red plot has baseValue = tip value of the yellow. I used CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase to change the baseValue of the red plot(set barBaseValue= Yes). As my expect, the total value of both plots at that index = 190+63.3=253.3. Unfortunately, the outcome of the total is only 190 which is value of red plot only.

Thus, My question is how can I still display values of plots graph in this format, but the total height of 2 plots at this index must be 253.3(I dont need to display this number). I just want to make the graph height looked right to its value like this one

[image]

This plot has total value is 97 which is little below 100.

Please help me. I appreciate the helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Plot doesn't do the stacking calculations for you. Make the tip value of the red bar 253.3 (190 + 63.3).

Comment: Thanks Eric, I thought about it, but it didnt work in my case. If I make value of the red become 253.3(which is the sum), then the label would be 253.3 also. That is not what I want. I want it show 190. Is there any ways to modify the label value? If so, I can solve the problem. Please help me.

Comment: Eric, have you used "shouldStack" member before? I did a lot of research and it came up, but I not sure it is what I need. Thank you

Comment: The `shouldStack` property was part of a patch that a user put together but it was never added into the base Core Plot project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok just want to share. As Eric pointed out "Make the tip value of the red bar 253.3 (190 + 63.3)", but he didn't mention how. Here is how I did it. First, plot a red bar with value is total of 2 values(red+yellow). Then plot the yellow bar overlap the red one and it has a same the baseValue with the red plot. Here is the trick, when I label te red plot, I used its actual value which is not total value. And here is the func that I used to modify the labels.

```
-(CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
CPTTextLayer *label;
if (red_plot.identifier){
    label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_charDataOfRed objectAtIndex:index]]]; 
}
else{
    label = [[CPTTextLayer alloc] initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_charDataOfYellow objectAtIndex:index]]]; 
}
CPTMutableTextStyle *textStyle = [label.textStyle mutableCopy];
textStyle.color = [CPTColor redColor];
label.textStyle = textStyle;
[textStyle release];
return [label autorelease];
```

Hope this can help!